# Python Proxy Server + HTTP Analyzer

Tags: python, http, proxy, analyzer

I am new to Python, and servers in general, and would really appreciate if someone points me in the right direction.  I have tried searching on Google, but haven't been able to find something that fits what I need.

I want to have a Python server monitoring the traffic coming through it.  I am expecting certain URLs.  If particular GET requests come through, I want to be able to parse and log the parameters.  If JSON is sent through, I want to read and extract data from it.  What are the steps to do this?